# wp_update_post - Update custom post_type with custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

How to update the custom post_type custom fields? Is it possible using **wp_update_post** ?

In this function's arguments I couldn't find **post_type**. Is **wp_update_post** the right function for the purpose? Thanks for the help in advance.

I have custom post type **crb_expense**. I would like to update it's title, content, custom fields and taxonomy related with it. Here I just test if it works only with title and the content:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['edit'] ) && $_GET['edit'] != 0 ) {
    wp_update_post( [
        'ID'           => $_GET['edit'],
        'post_type'    => 'crb_expense',
        'post_title'   => 'This is the new post title.',
        'post_content' => 'This is the new updated content.',
    ] );
}
```

. **$_GET['edit']** contains the id of the post which is comming from ajax request. I have cheched it and the id is correct.

Comment: where are you using `wp_update_post`? be more detailed

Comment: ok, add your comment into your question( edit it )

Comment: you have to use the following for custom fields `update_post_meta($id,'fieldkey', $_REQUEST['fieldvalue']);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**wp_update_post** is working based on $post object so kindly check below code how you can edit particular custom post type with custom fields.

**Update post title and content only**

```
 $post_id =1;

  // Update post 1
     $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id ,
      'post_title'   => 'This is the post title.',
      'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
     );

    // Update the post into the database
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

**Update post meta**

```
 update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
```

So using one function you can't edit post title, content and meta as well. Of you want to edit any custom fields then you have to use **update_post_meta** function.

This is working for me I hope it will help you as well.

Comment: It helps me a lot! Thank you. Can you tell me How to update which custom taxonomy is related to the post?

Comment: wp_update_term() function is used for any taxonomy which you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me

```
$my_post = array(
  'ID'           => $post_id ,
  'post_title'   =>  $title,
   'meta_input' => array(
          '_joelsa_dev_email' => $email,
          '_joelsare_Personalstatement' => $personalstatement,
          '_joelsa_dev_current_job' => $currentjob,
          '_joelsa_dev_experience' => $experience,
          '_joelsa_dev_relocate' => $relocate,
          '_joelsa_dev_telephone' => $telephone,
          '_joelsa_dev_github' => $github,
          '_joelsa_dev_linkedin' => $linkedin,
          '_joelsa_dev_country' => $country,
          '_joelsa_dev_cv' => $cvurl,
            ),
 );

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```